# -n Vs !(exclamation mark) behaves differently with test command

Tags: test

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A numMap
numMap[1]=1
#case-one
if ! [[ ${numMap[1]} ]];then
  echo "case-one: the key 1 for numMap array is not set"
fi
#case-two
if [[ -n ${numMap[1]} ]]; then
  echo "case-two: the key 1 for numMap array is not set"
fi
```

I expect both `! [[ ${numMap[1]} ]]` and `[[ -n ${numMap[1]} ]]` to be falsy, since `numMap[1]` contains a valid value - `1`. But when i run the code, it prints

```
case-two: the key 1 for numMap array is not set
```

Why does, `[[ -n ${numMap[1]} ]]` get evaluated as true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[[ -n ${numMap[1]} ]]` tests if the string is *not* empty. It isn't, so the test returns true.

Comment: thanks, i thought, `n` stands for the string being `null`...

Comment: The tests are `-n` and `-z` so you can think of them as testing if the string length is non-zero or zero.